# Running clojure project does not compile on Heroku - memoize error

Tags: heroku, clojure

Here's the error I get deploying to Heroku:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: clojure.core.cache/through, compiling:(clojure/core/memoize.clj:52:3)

This project runs fine on my local machine.  This particular dependency is for some Compojure middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the application is started on heroku, using a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-clojure#declare-process-types-with-procfile) that probably looks like this:

```
 web: java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/helloworld-standalone.jar clojure.main -m hello.world $PORT
```

May brings slightly different dependency sets. 
Make sure you have this in your project.clj

```
  [org.clojure/core.cache "0.6.4"]
```

You can make sure it works on your machine first using the same classpath by using [foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/) to control your application on your local machine too.